# Infoview report returns results when run on demand but not when scheduled

Tags: business-objects, infoview

Business Objects infoview report returns results when I refresh in the report but if I schedule it returns no results. I know there is data because it returns when report is refreshed, and when the SQL is run in SQL dev. I must be able to schedule for larger report runs. I have tried logging out/in, saving as a different name, and checking prompts. Any suggestions would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: What type of document are you using (e.g. Crystal Reports, Web Intelligence, ...)? InfoView is just the web application, not a document type. Also, is the data provider perhaps using a SSO end-to-end connection (i.e. SSO to the database)?

Comment: This is a web intelligence report. Other web intelligence reports in this domain work when scheduled so i think it has to be something specific to this report.

Comment: When you say NO Results after scheduling, do you see the status of the schedule in history as "Success"?

Comment: Yes status is Success and its running well under the timeout limit

Comment: so when you click on the result you see blank report? also is there any specific format you are scheduling this report too? if not try exporting to PDF and see atleast if that shows data?

Comment: Yes the tables are empty. I have tried exporting to excel without success

Comment: Did you try rebooting the scheduling adaptive servers?

Comment: Rebooting was successful in fixing this issue